# Structogram too long

Tags: page-breaking, struktex

I'm using`struktex` to design some long structograms.

**Does anyone know how to have a long structogram be separated onto the next page?**

I guess the easy fix would be to "cut it" where I see it reaches the end of the page and make a new one in the next one, but the idea does not satisfy me at all. The how-to is not very detailed and only shows short examples.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems that there is not a command to allow linebreaks.

Comment: The `struktogramm` environment does its work in a `picture` environment nested inside a `minipage`. So there's no way to break it across pages, because it's impossible with `picture` to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of the `struktogramm` environment:

```
140 \def\struktogramm(#1,#2){%
141     \let\ifthenelse=\ifthenelse@nss%
142     \let\ifend=\ifend@nss%
143     \ifdraft@nss\let\struktogramm@nss=\struktogramm@Proof\fi%
144     \@ifnextchar [{\struktogramm@nss(#1,#2)}{\struktogramm@nss(#1,#2)[]}%
145 }
146 \def\endstruktogramm{%
147             \endstr@kt%
148         \end{picture}%
149     \end{minipage}%
150     \setlength{\unitlength}{\savelength@nss}%
151 }
```

The `\struktogramm@nss` command is usually equivalent to `\struktogramm@NoProof` (unless the `draft` option is passed), which is defined by

```
152 \def\struktogramm@NoProof(#1,#2)[#3]{%
153     \def\next{#3}
154     \setlength{\savelength@nss}{\unitlength}
155     \setlength{\unitlength}{0.001mm}
156     \begin{minipage}[\Position@nss]{#1mm}
157         \ifx\next\empty\else #3\\[\smallskipamount]\fi%
158         \begin{picture}(#1000,#2000)%
159             \str@kt{0}{#2000}{#1000}%
160 }
```

The consequence is that `struktogramm` is a `minipage` with a nested `picture` environment. It's no different when `draft` is activated.

There's no way to split a `picture` environment across pages, therefore, sorry, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! Since I'm not writing a line-by-line diagram, I'll resort to making a very small one, some explanation text, then another one for the following block of code.